# How to send push notifications to multiple users using GCM

Tags: android, .net, google-cloud-messaging

I followed some demo's and its working fine in my mobile. But i have some questions. Is Registration Id is unique for application or user? If it is unique for user then how to save multiple regID's in server(dot net). Please give me some guidance.

Comment: Yes registration id is unique for every user. For sending push notifications you neeed the unique id of users so you can send to specific end users or to all. Anyways you need to store the reg id s in some DB or file.

Comment: thanks for reply. can u explain how to get regID's to our server from GCM server?

Comment: String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If it is unique for user then how to save multiple regID's in server(dot net). Please give me some guidance.

When the device registered with the GCM server, the device MUST send that unique ID to your server, and then you save that value for sending messages.

> How to send push notifications to multiple users using GCM?

You create message with a format. For multiple IDs, just fill the `registration_ids` key with **your user IDs in the form of array object**

Example in python:

```
ids=[]
query= // get all user record from database
for q in query:
    ids.append(q.registration_id)
// some code
jsonmessage=json.dumps({
    "registration_ids":ids,
    "data":{
        "message":message,
        "time":datetime.datetime.today().isoformat(),
        "sender":sender
     }
})
conn.send(jsonmessage)
```

That will look like this:

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyB-1uEai2WiUapxCs2Q0GZYzPu7Udno5aA
{
  "registration_ids" : ["APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...", "second_id", "third_id"],
  "data" : {
    ...
  },
}
```

Comment: @Zyoo - is it possible to send different message to multiple users (array of registration ids) using single request?

Comment: @rafi, as far as i know, if you want to send different messages you should use different requests

Answer (score 0):

Yes registration ID is unique to particular User for particular application. You can create your databse and store them all

Answer (score 0):

You can send multicase messages to upto 1000 users at once. See Google's guide:

http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html

Apart from that, You can make an array of all registered users and send messages to all of them individually one-by-one.

Comment: How to save or get regId's into my server?

Comment: If you are following the example, then regID's are already in your server. If they weren't, you wouldn't be able to send push messages. Now to access them - This depends on your database structure. You need to examine the database, find out where regID's are stored and write methods to access them.

Comment: google doesn't send you regID's. Each device will register with your server and will give it a unique regID. Your server will use this regID and your apps API key to send a message to GCM server which the GCM server will deliver to your device. So all regID's of all devices that have registered to receive push messages from your app will already be present in your server.

Comment: oh..k. So, we have to send regId's from app itself right? do you have any sample code for this?

Comment: refer this tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#arch), a `RegId` is:

> An ID issued by the GCM servers to the Android application that allows
>   it to receive messages. Once the Android application has the
>   registration ID, it sends it to the 3rd-party application server,
>   which uses it to identify each device that has registered to receive
>   messages for a given Android application. In other words, a
>   registration ID is tied to a particular Android application running on
>   a particular device.

So a `RegId` is Application and User specific.

For storing, you can send a Post after the registration of GCM complete. Use the sample apps provided by Google and you will get some clues.

Comment: what methods are required to call or save multiple regID's in our server?

Comment: you can import the sample apps from Android, or [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)